App works from signed APK but fails when installed from Play Store
The signed APK and the APK split from the signed app bundle work fine, but installing the app from the Play Store shows an error. I tried it on my IDEMIA screen device; when building the signed APK, it works. Even when uploading the app bundle to the Play Console and installing the APK from the console, it also works. Creating the AAB file and splitting the APKs using bundletool also works. The issue only occurs when installing from the Play Store.
I tried changing the ProGuard rules and setting isMinifyEnabled = false and isShrinkResources = false, but there is still no solution. Can anyone help me in identifying exactly where the problem is? If getting the APK from the signed bundle works, why is it not working when installed from the Play Store?
Note: My app contains 3 projects in build.grade

Impossible to tell without the actual error. Do you have it?

It shows third party sdk not available when installing from play-store.

Please post an actual error message or stack trace.
